# How to use boost program_options to consume/remove an option in ARGV after usage

Tags: c++, boost, command-line-arguments, boost-program-options

Currently, our codebase is using boost program_options as command-line parser in our testing framework. I want to implement a "consume-after-use" kind of rule in our command-line parsing.

What I mean by "consume-after-use" is, for example. After --option1 is used, I can then remove this --option1 in ARGC, ARGV. The main reason for this is I want to pass ARGC, and ARGV in another parser after I use the options I'm only concerned with.

Is this possible in boost program_option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can read [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/boost/program_options/variables_map.html) the `boost::program_options::variables_map` inherites from std::map, so you can call `std::map:erase` on it:

```
namespace po = boost::program_options;

po::variables_map vm;
po::store(po::parse_command_line(ac, av, desc), vm);
po::notify(vm);

if (vm.count("option1")) {
    // handle option1
    ...
    // erase option1
    vm.erase("option1");
    if (vm.count("option1")) {
      // never gonna happen
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i didnt know i could do that XD.